# unpivot with a flag in Oracle

Tags: sql, unpivot, oracle19c

I have this table structure

ID,SUPPLIER_GROUP1,SUPPLIER1,SUPPLIER_GROUP2,SUPPLIER2.

i want to unpivot and get

ID,SUPPLIER_GROUP,SUPPLIER,TYPE

so each supplier_group and supplier values come to the appropriate column and in TYPE column will be either 1 or 2 to see if the SUPPLIER_GROUP and SUPPLIER value was supplier1 or supplier2 .

Comment: Hi @Pato, have you tried any code yourself ? Also, can we get a two rows of data as example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNPIVOT` with multiple column groups:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT (
  (supplier_group, supplier) FOR type IN (
    (supplier_group1, supplier1) AS 1,
    (supplier_group2, supplier2) AS 2
  )
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID,SUPPLIER_GROUP1,SUPPLIER1,SUPPLIER_GROUP2,SUPPLIER2) AS
SELECT 1, 'sg1.1', 's1.1', 'sg2.1', 's2.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'sg1.2', 's1.2', 'sg2.2', 's2.2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'sg1.3', 's1.3', 'sg2.3', 's2.3' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | ID | TYPE | SUPPLIER_GROUP | SUPPLIER |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | sg1.1 | s1.1 |
> | 1 | 2 | sg2.1 | s2.1 |
> | 2 | 1 | sg1.2 | s1.2 |
> | 2 | 2 | sg2.2 | s2.2 |
> | 3 | 1 | sg1.3 | s1.3 |
> | 3 | 2 | sg2.3 | s2.3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4a1c3d9506eefca402187b74eca690f3)*